# WC Cart Widget/mini-cart not showing cart subtotal since WC 3.2.0 update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Ever since today's update (WooCommerce 3.2.0) the cart subtotal in the mini-cart has been showing $0.00 no matter what is in the cart.

Has anybody else been having this issue? I've attempted overriding mini-cart.php to fix the issue but that didn't work.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Right after I updated to 3.2.1 yesterdat, the subtotal in the mini-cart always shows 0 no matter the content. Currently trying to find a fix.

Comment: Are you using the plugin Dynamic Pricing from Lucas Stark? In my case I solved the problem by updating Dynamic Pricing to version 3.1.1. If possible, try to deactivate all your plugins to see if the subtotal now shows correctly, and then one by one active your plugins until the problem occur.